# mean vs fivenum: different results?

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
> foo
 [1]   0   0 159  24   0 829   0 157  46  12   5   5 166 166   5  12   5   5 166 166   5  35
> mean(foo)
[1] 89.45455
> summary(fivenum(foo))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       5      12     201     159     829
```

What the smeg? I can't understand why fivenum computes a different number from "mean". I guess the problem is me but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you calling `summary` on `fivenum`?

Compare:

```
foo <- c(0, 0, 159, 24, 0, 829, 0, 157, 46, 12, 5, 5, 166, 166, 5, 12, 
         5, 5, 166, 166, 5, 35)
> mean(foo)
[1] 89.45455
> summary(foo)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    5.00   12.00   89.45  158.50  829.00 
> fivenum(foo)
[1]   0   5  12 159 829
> mean(fivenum(foo))
[1] 201
> summary(fivenum(foo))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       5      12     201     159     829
```

`fivenum` returns a vector of length five that *"Returns Tukey's five number summary (minimum, lower-hinge, median, upper-hinge, maximum) for the input data."*. Note that there is no mention of `mean` in there :)

So, when you do `summary(fivenum(foo))` you are calculating summary statistics for the vector `c(0, 5, 12, 159, 829)`. For that vector, the `mean` is, indeed 201.

Comment: + 1 -- also mention that `fivenum` doesn't calculate the mean either.

Comment: @mnel, Done. Was editing my answer to show the first line of the help page.

Comment: *headslap* So dumb. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel: should be ***facepalm***

Comment: @Daniel, don't worry about it. We all have those days :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add couple of more points here as I see a few getting confused between the quartiles given by summary() and fivenum().

Firstly - summary() gives the following summary statistics:
[Minimum] [1st Quartile] [Median] [Mean] [3rd Quartile] [Maximum]

where as,

fivenum() returns Tukey's five number summary i.e.
[Minimum] [Lower hinge] [Median] [Upper hinge] [Maximum]

Here comes the confusion - what's the difference between the quartiles and lower/upper hinges?

Let me explain with an example - Try this in R:

First - with a vector "y" of odd number of values (5 in this example)

```
> > y=c(2, 5, 8, 15, 8)
> > summary(y)    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>     2.0     5.0     8.0     7.6     8.0    15.0 
> > fivenum(y) [1]  2  5  8  8 15
```

As you can see results are the same, except that summary() gave the mean value in addition to what fivenum() displayed.

Now I am including just one more variable (new value: 12) and defined this vector as "z"; Note that the vector count is now even (6 values)

```
> z=c(2, 5, 8, 12, 15, 18)
> summary(z)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00    5.75   10.00   10.00   14.25   18.00 
> fivenum(z)
[1]  2  5 10 15 18
```

Now see the difference - while summary() gave you the quartiles (calculated values based on quartile or percentile formulae), this is what fivenum() does - making it really simple - you can do it without math calculations:

> Description of fivenum() output:
>
> Firstly, min, median & max values given by fivenum() are straight
> forward!
>
> Lower Hinge = median of the values to the left of (MEDIAN OF ALL
> VALUES) = median of the values that are less than 10 = median of
> (2,5,8) = 5
>
> Upper hinge = median of the values to the right of (MEDIAN OF ALL
> VALUES) = median of the values that are greater than 10 = median of
> (12,15,18) = 15